# Google Visualization: Line Chart

Tags: html, google-visualization

how can I set the opacity of all the series not selected to near 0?

(Hover over "Sales" in the example, and "Expenses" should get more translucent)
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Methods

Comment: You can only control the opacity of data points in a series; you cannot make the line itself opaque.

Making a data series opaque *may* be possible on hover, but I foresee a bunch of problems with it.  Doing it on select would be much easier.

Comment: @asgallant I don't know if you mean the same thing as me. I got many series (about 80) and you should be able to see a selected one clear when selecting it on the right side. The effect is already visible, but just not enough.

Comment: The hover effect on the legend creates a shadow, not a change in opacity, but alas, the effect is not configurable.

Comment: @asgallant So you think it's not possible to somehow "mark" one series more than by default? Thanks for your help though ;)

Comment: It is conceivable that you could use onmouseover/onmouseout events to change a series color.  Doing so would involve redrawing the chart, and I don't believe mouse state is preserved across draws, so you may have some strange side effects (like the series color not returning to normal on mouse out).  I'll think on this and see what I can come up with.